# Delay while loading WPF page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Button on Page 1 and on Button_click Doing some operations with a background worker and showing the progress and once the operation is finished , application
loads a new page like this

```
Uri ViewPageUri = new System.Uri("View.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
private void bookOpeningWorker_WorkFinished(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(ViewPageUri);            
    }
}
```

Inside View Page Loaded event doing some other time consuming operations in a Background worker and showing the waiitng progress.

The second page contains few user controls and some other browser controls , but all the operations are performing on Load event of the page

All things are working fine , but the only issue is application is taking some time to finish execution between the lines NavigationService.Navigate and Loaded event of the Page 
So i am getting a delay of 3-4 seconds betweeen this time and no progress or waiting messages are visible to end user and also i can see the pointer in a waiting mode .

Is there any specific reason for this effect?or any better way to improve the code?

Comment: The page needs to be loaded _asynchronously_, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17279898/815938) can get you started, but you need to write download the code inside `Page_Load` and analyze which steps are time consuming.

Comment: In my case the delay i am getting is to get to the first line in the constructor of the Page after executing the NavigationService.Navigate command. .